# Hide content within element without hiding child class

Tags: jquery

I am using a form wizard plugin that produces the following HTML

```
<li role="tab" class="first current" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true">
     <a id="form-3-t-0" href="#form-3-h-0" aria-controls="form-3-p-0">   
          <span class="current-info audible">current step: </span>
          <span class="number">1.</span> 
          Text I want to hide
     </a>
</li>
```

I want to simply display the step number when the device is smaller than 768px.

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to hide/remove "Text I want to hide" because it does
not belong to an element I can target directly.

Can anyone help me hide the text without hiding `class="number"` at the same time?
My attempt does not work. It hides the number class even though I tell it not to.

```
 if($(window).width() <= 1024) {    
      $('.steps a:not(".number")').text('');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the text, try:

```
$("#form-3-t-0").contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;  
}).remove();
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66WGQ/)

Comment: @MarkusProctor you could mark it as Accepted answer if it worked for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(window).width() <= 1024) {    
      var toBeAdded=$('.number');
      toBeAdded.appendTo($('.steps').text(''));
 }
```

Comment: Maybe add a little bit of text to explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $form = $('#form-3-t-0'),
$number = $('a').find('span.number');

    $form.html('');
    $form.append($number);
```

This creates a variable that remembers what you want to keep, deletes everything inside and returns the number to its rightful place.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bkanq